# Invalid URL in Hive JDBC

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

Whenin Hive on Connecting through JDBC Hive

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid URL:jdbc:hive2://192.
168.14.52:10000/report

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:23)
```

Comment: url looks fine, try adding ;auth=noSasl

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the right driver class (org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)?  The driver class changes between the different versions of Hive.

See this post: [Jdbc Hive2 Invalid Url Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231049/jdbc-hive2-invalid-url-exception)

Comment: It is definitely the wrong driver, it can be seen in the stack trace (org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)